# Que signifie « l'allocation des épouses » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Je n'ai pas pu saisir le sens exact de l'expression « l'allocation des épouses » dans ce contexte (*[Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique](http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html)* de Georges Balandier dans les *Cahiers internationaux de sociologie*, vol. 76, janvier-juin 1984, pp. 5-19):

> Lévi-Strauss a souligné le fait fondamental que ce sont les hommes qui échangent les femmes, non le contraire. Il en résulte un pouvoir global des hommes sur les femmes. L'essentiel, c'est la transformation des femmes en véritables opérateurs sociaux par le moyen desquels se fixe la Loi (prohibition de l'inceste), se constituent des rapports sociaux primaires (parenté et alliance) et la première forme du pouvoir (capacité reconnue d'effectuer **l'allocation des épouses**).

Comment: Merci d'indiquer la provenance des textes cités.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html § Loi et transgression

Answer (score 1):

La femme étant mineure sociale, les hommes se sont reconnus la capacité  d'effectuer *l'allocation des épouses*, c'est-à-dire de se partager la population féminine nubile selon des codes et règles par eux seuls décidées.

*La distribution, la répartition des femmes* (consentantes ou non) à marier et ainsi à assurer une descendance, une lignée à la communauté, se fait selon des règles patriarcales.

Ce partage réglé, on peut dire que *l'allocation des épouses* est faite, jusqu'à ce que de nouvelles jeunes femmes en âge de se marier arrivent.

Answer (score 1):

"Allocation" est employée pour de la distribution de bien (allocation chômage, scolaire, universel : l'état distribue de l'argent aux contribuables), ou dans un cadre informatique (allouer une ressource à un programme). Dans chaque cas une entité organisatrice répartie des ressources.

Dans le contexte, cela signifie que des hommes choisissent avec qui les femmes seront mariées ("allouer" à quel homme).

Comment: Je ne mettrais pas en avant l’utilisation en informatique, qui est complètement spécialisée (un non-informaticien n’y songerait pas). De plus, je n’irai pas jusqu’à parler de « considérées comme des biens matériels »; le fait qu’elles n’aient pas leur mot à dire sur la question suffit déjà à établir un rapport de pouvoir en faveur du mâle sans aller jusque-là.

Comment: Déformation professionnel.. Mais c'est également les deux exemples que donne wikipedia pour "allocation". Et vous avez raison, je vais éditer la deuxième partie.

Answer (score 0):

"allocation" est un nom dérivé du verbe "allouer". "allocation" -> "le fait d'allouer", tout simplement.

Comment: Ce qui veut dire... ? :)

Comment: Allouer = attribuer, assigner. Ce passage dit en gros que la première forme du pouvoir, c'est la capacité communément acceptée de dire "Alice est la femme de Bernard".

Answer (score 0):

"Allocation" , comme le dit Anne Aunyme, doit être compris ici comme le substantif de "allouer", avec pour synonyme "assigner", "attribuer".
En informatique, par exemple, on parle d'**allocation de mémoire** : c'est le fait de réserver une place en mémoire pour une variable. Synonyme : réserver.

Ici l'**allocation des épouses** désigne le fait d'attribuer des femmes comme épouses, comme si elles étaient un bien que l'on distribue ou partage.

Answer (score -1):

Allouer veut dire attribuer c'est comme si les hommes s'attribuaient des femmes comme des biens personnels (objets)